# Solving heat equation in the given form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $a,b$ be constants with $a>0.$ Consider the IVP
$$u_t=a \Delta u+b |\nabla u|^2=0~~\textrm{in}~~R^n \times (0,\infty), u=g~~\textrm{on}~~R^n \times \{ t=0 \}.$$
Solve this by using the solution formula for $w,$ where
$$w_t-a \Delta w =0~~\textrm{in}~~R^n \times (0,\infty), w=h~~\textrm{on}~~R^n \times \{ t=0 \}.$$

I've got no idea on how to go by and solving this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical solution?

Comment: @caverac no, pencil and paper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off let's point out that you have a typo in your statement.  The equation for $w$ should be $w_t - a \Delta w =0$.  I know this is true because I know the trick to solve the problem using such a $w$, but we can also see this directly because $w_t$ is scalar and $a \nabla w$ is a vector.

Here's a nice hint for the problem that doesn't give away everything.  Suppose initially that we have a solution $u$ to the problem.  Define a new function $v(x,t) = \varphi(u(x,t))$ for some $C^2$ function $\varphi$.
$$
 v_t = \varphi'(u)  u_t, \nabla v = \varphi'(u) \nabla u, \Delta v = \varphi'(u) \Delta u + \varphi''(u) \vert\nabla u\vert^2
$$
and so
$$
 v_t - a \Delta v    = \varphi'(u) [  u_t - a \Delta u  ] +   a\varphi''(u) \vert\nabla u\vert^2 \\
= [b\varphi'(u)    + a\varphi''(u)] \vert\nabla u\vert^2. 
$$
This analysis is valid for ANY $\varphi$, so now you can try to choose $\varphi$ such that $v=w$.

From here you should be able to finish the problem yourself.

Comment: thank you very much. I fixed the typo. I can't see for what function I get the equality for $v=w$ and what solution formula to use. But your answer gives me a heads up.

Comment: do you know a good reference to refer to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking because you're still stuck?  Need another hint?

Comment: By starting as $u=\phi(w),$  I was able to get $$\phi = \frac{b}{a} \ln \left ( \frac{a}{b} w \right ).$$ What's the specific solution formula they refer here ? Yeah, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Do you know the heat kernel and how to use it to solve the heat equation?

Comment: I've done it for the two-dimensional case. Not for a general dimension. May be not have a clear picture of that is my biggest issue here.